# how to redirect? mapping? url in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

i have poll app

following is my root urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('poll/', include('myproject.poll.urls')),
]
```

and I have app url

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'', PollViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls))
]
```

i used ViewSet so I can use `reverse('poll-list')`, `reverse('poll-detail')`...

and i can access `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/poll` and `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/poll/1/` ....

but I want to redirect(mapping?) url when i access `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/v1/poll/` to `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/poll`

I don't want to change existing urls.

because I want to bundle the views of several apps into one api url file.

How can i do that? and what is the best way?

Comment: You add a second line to your root urls file or configure your webserver to handle it.

Comment: Use DRF Routers. In routers there is  a setting to set trailing slash `False`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it in two ways:

**Add mapping url in root urls and keep app url intact:**

root url look like:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('poll/', include('myproject.poll.urls')),
    path('api/v1/poll/', include('myproject.poll.urls')),
]
```

this will not redirect but your API (app urls) will be serve from both urls

**Add RedirectView**

```
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView

urlpatterns = [
    path('poll/', include('myproject.poll.urls')),
    path('api/v1/poll/', RedirectView.as_view(url='/poll/')),
]
```

This will redirect all request of `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/v1/poll/` to `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/poll/`